# Is it possible to disaggregate in hive sql?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I want to achieve what's described here:

http://codecorner.galanter.net/2012/04/25/t-sql-string-deaggregate-split-ungroup-in-sql-server/

That is, take data that looks like this:

```
Country  FirstNames
UK       Anne,Michael,Robert,Steven
USA      Andrew,Janet,Laura,Margaret,Nancy
```

and turn it into:

```
Country FirstName
UK      Anne
UK      Michael
UK      Robert
UK      Steven
USA     Andrew
USA     Janet
USA     Laura
USA     Margaret
USA     Nancy
```

I know there is a `split` and `explode` function. But `explode` can only be used as a single expression (cannot participate with other items) in `select`.

Comment: Personally, I would do this using Spark

Comment: why do it with spark instead?

Comment: Because I like Python/Scala better than SQL :D

Comment: curious about that. how would a basic python script for this look like?

Comment: I wouldn't call PySpark "basic Python"